# Find and replace numbers in multiple text files with the original number modified?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need to find all strings "5dp" and replace them with with "(5*0.83)dp", rounded down to integers. The number 5 could be any number, and the expression in the brackets is actually executed.

For example: `31dp` should become `25dp`.

I need to search all files in the directory and sub directories recursively.
Any help?

Comment: You mean instead of the stuff in the brackets you want a floating point number followed by "dp", right?

Comment: I want the 5 from the original text to be replaced with itself * 0.83

Comment: Should it be rounded? could be extended floats :)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot! only whole numbers.

Comment: Up or down, or mathematical? All can be done :)

Comment: down would work best, :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` + Perl:

```
find . -type f -exec \
perl -i -e 'use POSIX;' -pe 's/([0-9]*)dp/floor($1*.83).dp/ge' {} +
```

`find` command:

- `.`: searches in the current working directory hierarchy;
- `-type f`: searches only for files;
- `-exec [...] {} +`: executes the following command feeding it the search results as a list of arguments;

Perl command:

- `-i`: specifies that files processed by the `<>` construct are to be edited in-place;
- `-p`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around the program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like `sed`: `while (<>) {...} continue {print or die "-p destination: $!\n";}`;
- `-e`: used to enter one line of program; Perl will not look for a filename in the argument list;

Perl command #1 breakdown:

- `use POSIX;`: imports the `POSIX` module, needed for the `POSIX::floor` function;

Perl command #2 breakdown:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: stops the command / starts the pattern
- `(`: starts the capturing group
- `[0-9]*`: matches any number of any digit
- `)`: stops the capturing group
- `dp`: matches a `dp` string
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `floor($1*.83).dp`: Perl expression replaced with the result of `floor($1*.83)` (where `$1` is the captured group) followed by a `dp` string
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the options
- `g`: asserts to perform substitutions globally
- `e`: asserts to execute the replacement string as a Perl command

Sample output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ tree
.
└── 1
    ├── 2
    │   ├── 3
    │   │   └── infile
    │   └── infile
    └── infile

3 directories, 3 files
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo -e "{}:\n\n$(cat {})\n"' \;
./1/infile:

1dp 2dp 3dp 4dp 5dp
6dp 7dp 8dp 9dp 10dp
11dp 12dp 13dp 14dp 15dp

./1/2/infile:

1dp 2dp 3dp 4dp 5dp
6dp 7dp 8dp 9dp 10dp
11dp 12dp 13dp 14dp 15dp

./1/2/3/infile:

1dp 2dp 3dp 4dp 5dp
6dp 7dp 8dp 9dp 10dp
11dp 12dp 13dp 14dp 15dp

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ find . -type f -exec perl -i -e 'use POSIX;' -pe 's/([0-9]*)dp/floor($1*.83).dp/ge' {} +
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo -e "{}:\n\n$(cat {})\n"' \;
./1/infile:

0dp 1dp 2dp 3dp 4dp
4dp 5dp 6dp 7dp 8dp
9dp 9dp 10dp 11dp 12dp

./1/2/infile:

0dp 1dp 2dp 3dp 4dp
4dp 5dp 6dp 7dp 8dp
9dp 9dp 10dp 11dp 12dp

./1/2/3/infile:

0dp 1dp 2dp 3dp 4dp
4dp 5dp 6dp 7dp 8dp
9dp 9dp 10dp 11dp 12dp
```

Comment: Understandably, you might have missed the comments that lead to the conclusion that the output should be rounded down to integers. I edited it into the question now.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes I did, thanks for pointing that out, It's fixed now

Comment: Ah, thanks. I Just also noticed you missed: *I need to search all files in the directory and sub directories* (which I didn't add, it was there from the beginning :) )

Comment: @JacobVlijm Indeed I did, thanks again and fixed that as well (and if I missed something else then I'm done for today). :)

Comment: Works fine, +1 Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks, upvoted yours already before, although I've tested it on a single file, but I'm positive it works also recursively. :)

Comment: Awesome how would I search for dp" instead (double quote after dp)?

Comment: @Scott Just add it to the pattern and to the replacement string: `find . -type f -exec perl -i -e 'use POSIX;' -pe 's/([0-9]*)dp"/floor($1*.83).dp"/ge' {} +`

Answer (score 1):

A lot more verbose: the python script below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

directory = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        subject = root+"/"+file
        text = open(subject).read().split(" ")
        for i, s in enumerate(text):
            if s.endswith("dp"):
                try:
                    n = str(int(float(s.replace("dp", ""))*0.83))+"dp"; text[i] = n
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        open(subject, "wt").write((" ").join(text))
```

#### How to use it

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `replace_numbers.py`
- Run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/replace_numbers.py <directory>
  ```

#### An example

`a monkey eats 234dp bananas, while 2657dp would be too much. 234 is more the 12.`

becomes:

`a monkey eats 194dp bananas, while 2205dp would be too much. 234 is more the 12.`

#### Explanation:

- The script opens all files in a directory (one by one), reads them and splits it into strings.
- *IF* "dp" is in the string, it separates the number from "dp", (tries) to multiply it by `0.83`. Then the float is rounded down (using `int(<float>)`). If the string, stripped from "dp" appears to be not only a number, the process is skipped for the specific string (giving a `ValueError`)
- Once all occurrences of "dp" are passed, the text with the replaced numbers is written to the file again, replacing the original text.

Comment: You' re welcome. Interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's a solution with bash oneliners:

(Had that one ready before I read the OP wanted integers after all, thus the use of bc to do float math.)

```
find . -type f|while read f;do cat "$f"|while read a;do b=`echo "$a"|sed 's/.*\([0-9]\+\)dp.*/\1*0.83/'|bc`;echo "$a"|sed s/"[0-9]\+dp"/"$b"dp/;done;done
```

...and rounded down:

```
find . -type f|while read f;do cat "$f"|while read a;do b=`echo "$a"|sed 's/.*\([0-9]\+\)dp.*/\1*0.83/'|bc`;b=${b%.*};echo "$a"|sed s/"[0-9]\+dp"/"$b"dp/;done;done
```